# How to create a Java 2-Step authentication on Java 8?

Tags: java, authentication

**Hello everyone at StackOverflow,**

I will be asking a question that I'm confused about and searched for hours for, it's to put a 2-Step authentication on a Java program, what I want is that is send a generated code to a login page like the one I created below.

```
package log;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your username");
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your password");

        if (

                username != null && password != null &&
                (

                    (username.equals("g17") && password.equals("ire35")) ||
                    (username.equals("ree") && password.equals("melikejava")) ||
                    (username.equals("citizenzap") && password.equals("javarules23"))||
                    (username.equals("devs") && password.equals("password"))
                )
           )
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!" );
        }   else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password! Try again later." );
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine with the code above, it's just that I want to send a randomly generated code to a phone number, like as I said before a 2-Step verification. Like Google has or Microsoft and etc. For example: You write a phone number, `123-456-7890`, then it sends a code to the phone number and it's says something like `Your code is 178634` then you write it into the input box, then it checks if it was the code it sent.

If the question I said is not specific enough or something like that please tell me.

Thanks and keep on coding!

-CitizenZap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you put your data in map, combine username, password, phoneNumber into one class, like UserInfo. Because you need to bind phoneNumber to user, or any phoneNumber after login is acceptable.

Then, you replace

```
    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!" );
    }
```

with

```
    String newPhoneNumber = null;

    {
            newPhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your phone number");
    }
```

You need to check if newPhoneNumber equals with the phoneNumber bind to the user.

```
    // this should be in a while(true) loop
    if (newPhoneNumber.equals(phoneNumber)) {
        sendSms(phoneNumber);
        String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your code");
        boolean result = validateAuthorizationCode(code); // here you validate the code
       if (result) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!" );
       } else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong code!" );
       }
    } else {
        noticeWrongNumber(newPhoneNumber); // tell him the number is wrong, please reinput.
    }
```

Comment: Hello Bejond, I am a little confused about the last part with the last part because there's an error and I'm not sure what to do since I don't have a great knowledge about Java, so if you don't mind if you could tell me a little better?

Comment: The sendSms(), noticeWrongNumber() are just method name, you need to define the methods and implement them. In a simple way, you can just print a message or show a dialog to tell user the newPhoneNumber is not found.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I just need them to do something?

Comment: of course. Not limited the methods, you can also add your own business.